# Wi-Fi Direct Connect Fails - Nexus 7

Tags: android, wifi-direct, nexus-7

On my Nexus 7 whenever I try to connect to my Galaxy Nexus, it fails immediately and returns the reason being 0 (which is very uninformative as 0 is error). However, trying to connect on my Galaxy Nexus has no such problems.  Any ideas?  Simply using the manager.connect method, nothing special is going on.  It doesn't seem to have any problems with the find peers method either.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nexus 7 is Android 4.1 or 4.2? 4.2 having problem like this.

Comment: It is running 4.2. I was unaware of this, what a bummer.